# angular 2 load component dynamically and place it anywhere

Tags: angular

I'm using angular2 beta9 and I want to load component dynamically and place it anywhere. In other words, override selector. I don't want to use DynamicComponentLoader.LoadAsRoot function. Because, it's not root component and LoadAsRoot function does not call lifeCycle hooks of the component/may be it's a bug/. Is there any idea to approach my goal?

Answer (score 2):

`loadAsRoot()` is designed for the root component only and the root component doesn't support `@Input()`. You can invoke this manually 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6223#issuecomment-195155190

> because you're wiring up everything manually you also need to manage the change detector. If you want to include the component in the application then you have to inject the ApplicationRef and to inject the ApplicationRef you have to use the long version of bootstrap

I don't know of other ways.

Comment: Thank you sir. Actually, I don't want use `loadAsRoot()`. I just need to override selector of the component and load dynamically. `loadIntoLocation` requires `ElementRef`. I can't pass `ElementRef` of any dom element